# Multiple Redirects on one HTML

Tags: html, redirect, web

I would like to create a page which redirects to several pages when it is pressed.

I have written the following code in order to try and do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/a" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/b" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/c" />
</head>
</html>
```

On the web server log, I see that a request was only sent to "c".

Why is that? 
And how can I create an HTML page with multiple redirects?

Comment: Where do you want pages `a` and `b` to open in

Comment: Unless you are really trying to annoy people, I cannot see any reason for doing this.  Just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

You will inevitably need to use javascript.

```
<script>
function redirect(){
windows.open("http://www.example.com/a")
windwos.open("http://www.example.com/b")
windwos.open("http://www.example.com/c")
}
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">
```

Didn't test but should suffice

Comment: it's `window.open` btw I think this won't work, it will probably just open the first window

Comment: Corrected and it should open the 3 windows as popup.

Comment: Yeah it works :) Tried it and I just had to accept multiple popup from the browser

Comment: is there a way achiving this without JS?? only pure HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you understand, when refresh means. Refreshing with 0 means the browser is immediately redirected to the address provided. As far as one browser tab can only show one web page, your example cannot work.

You need to consider using [Popups](http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/) or alike to show the user several pages at one time.